# Domain such that countable intersections of nonzero ideals are nonzero.

Tags: commutative-algebra

> **Definition**: Say that a domain $D$ with field of fractions $K$ satisfies **property $(\rho)$** if countable intersections of nonzero ideals are nonzero, or equivalently if $D[[x]]_{D \setminus 0} = K[[x]]$.

I'd like to get a better understanding of how strong property $(\rho)$ is. 
I might even lamely conjecture that any domain with property $(\rho)$ is a field.

EDIT: A similar, weaker, property in the literature is that of being **anti-archimedean**, i.e. $\bigcap a^nD \not=0$ for all $a \in D$, or equivalently, $D[[x]]_{D \setminus 0}$ is local (has one maximal ideal).

> **Question:** Do there exist non-field domains satisfying property $(\rho)$?

Of course any proper overring of such a ring will have this property too, so we could find a non-field valuation overring of $D$ having the property $(\rho)$ (if there weren't any, then the integral closure of $D$ would be $K$, hence $D = K$.)

So we've essentially reduced the question to valuation rings.  However, I haven't been able to construct a nontrivial example with the desired property or able to see why such examples couldn't exist.

The following observation shows that any ring with property $(\rho)$ will be extremely large.

> A ring $D$ with property $(\rho)$ is such that every proper saturated multiplicative set in $D$ is disjoint from uncountably many prime ideals.  Consequently, every ideal of a valuation ring with property $(\rho)$ must contain uncountably many prime ideals.

Suppose $S$ is a saturated multiplicative set disjoint from only countably many primes.  Then the localization $S^{-1}D$ has countably many primes, and by property $(\rho)$, there would be some $0 \not= a$ in the intersection of its primes, and thus $K = S^{-1}D[1/a]$.  But then picking $0 \not= d \in \bigcap a^n$ (using property $(\rho)$ again) and examining $1/d \in S^{-1}D[1/a]$ shows that $a$ is a unit in $S^{-1}D$.  Hence $K = S^{-1}D$ and $S = D \setminus 0$.  $\square$.

Comment: I'm not sure about the notation $D[[x]]_{D\setminus 0}$  Care to elaborate?

Comment: Sure! That refers to the localization of the ring of formal power series over $D$ at the set of nonzero elements of $D$.  In other words, it's the ring of all power series $F \in K[[x]]$ such that $dF \in D[[x]]$ for some $d \in D$.

Comment: I'm getting picture but need to let it stew for awhile.  Thanks!